# LaCie Bigdisk (2x250GB) clicks and whirrs like a bad disk drive

Tags: hard-drive, lacie

I have an old LaCie Bigdisk (2x250GB) with USB2 and Firewire 400 & 800 connectors.

After being unused for about five years, I connected it to my computer via USB and pressed the blue button on the front to switch it on but it did not appear as a disk on my Windows computer.

Listening carefully to the LaCie unit, I can hear what sounds like the disk drives spinning up and slowing down, and sometimes clicks like the heads moving.

How can I get my data off the unit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sound of disk drives repeatedly spinning up, clicking, slowing down, spinning up then slowing down again can indicate that they are not receiving sufficient power.

As we are going to be taking things apart, make sure to mark what goes where, in particular label the disk drives and the connectors they go to.

After removing the disk drives from the unit (two screws on the back - one hidden under the "warranty void" sticker, then pull out from the front; remove the disk drive screws and cables), they can be individually checked for functionality in a computer with an IDE interface.

Use something like [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to confirm that the disks can be read. The purpose of this is *not* to recover the data, just to confirm that the disk drives work. The data is actually spread across the two disks so larger files (e.g. typically TIFF images) will not be complete.

At this stage you could try using RAID data recovery software, but this may not be necessary.

The rest of the insides of the LaCie unit can be removed with just a few screws to yield three circuit boards: the small power button/light board, the PSU board, and the other board. The latter two are connected with a PCB header connector. Disconnect them (the red line in the following image). Next, disconnect the two power leads which go to the disk drives (from the purple-ringed location). You will be left with:

[image: Main boards in unit]

Next we need to be able to supply power to the disk drives. This can be done using a PC PSU... connect *nothing else* yet.

[image: Setup for data retrieval]

---

*Regarding the above image...*

The red lines indicate where the power from the external PSU goes to the disk drives.

The light circle is where a paper clip has been used to switch on the PSU (green to black).

The green oblong is the main LaCie circuit boards and the on/off switch board is in the blue circle.

[The mat the things are sitting on is an anti-static one, and the yellow thing it is connected to via the blue curly lead is an anti-static earthing plug with a 1 MΩ resistor in it. The disk drives are Hitachi Deskstar, model HDT725025VLAT80, dated Nov 2006. The Sharpie happens to be the right size to support the power lead to avoid stressing the PCB header connector; it was the same Sharpie as used to write A and B on the disk drives and IDE lead. This is not a product endorsement.]

---

Next, connect the original LaCie PSU to the power PCB. Connect the USB lead to the other board. Connect the two boards together carefully - we don't want to damage that connector.

Now, power on the PC PSU. You will hear the disk drives spin up. Then power on the LaCie power brick. The blue light on the on/off PCB may or may not come on, ideally not but let it flash for a while (if it does) and then press the switch to switch it off.

Connect the other end of the USB lead to a computer. Switch on the LaCie unit and wait for it to appear in Windows Explorer. Copy all the data off immediately.